# Array values in function

Tags: php, arrays, function

Got an array here:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Securitygroep
    [1] => Hoofdgroep
    [2] => Belangrijke Groep
    [3] => Testgroep2
    [4] => Beheergroep
    [5] => Mailgroep
    [6] => Domeingebruikers
    [7] => Gebruikers
)
```

How can I get all the values from the array in this function?

```
$check = $adldap->group()->info("//value from array");
```

Or do I have to execute this function in a sort of looping method?

Like this:

```
$check = $adldap->group()->info("Securitygroep");
$check = $adldap->group()->info("Hoofdgroep");
$check = $adldap->group()->info("Belangrijke Groep");
```

etc etc...

Comment: Do you have to send those values in a comma separated list?

Comment: No, it takes only one value a time. So I need a loop or something with `foreach`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it depends on what the `info()` method is doing. While you do not provide us such information, we are not able to give you the most accurate answer.

For example, if info method accepts array:

```
public function info(array $infos) {
    foreach ($infos as $info) {
        // do smth with each element
    }
}
```

you can pass the array straight to the function:

```
$check = $adldap->group()->info($array);
```

if the method accepts only one element, then you need to loop through the array and pass to the method:

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $check = $adldap->group()->info($value);
}
```

If the method accepts a lot of values at once, i.e. comma separated, you can implode the array

```
 $check = $adldap->group()->info(implode(',' ,$array));
```

Comment: `foreach` works and it only accepts one element, but it's looping the same value every time and that's "Testgroep2". How do I get all the different values to loop in the function?

Comment: Never mind, got it working now! I missed placed a `{`. Now it works perfectly. Thanks, you saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

```
$check = $adldap->group()->info(implode(",",$yourArray));
```

This will send all the array values to your function in a comma separated string, if that is what you needed.

Otherwise if that method takes only 1 value then you could loop through your array

```
foreach($myArray as $value)
{
    $check = $adldap->group()->info($value);
}
```

Comment: Yes, my function apparently takes only 1 value a time. So your foreach function works, but it's only looping 1 value from the array and that's "Testgroep2". Why is this happening?

Comment: That's not possible provided the array structure is exactly like you mentioned and if the names match too

Answer (score 0):

Can the info method be rewritten to accept array as the parameter? Then simply pass it

```
$check = $adldap->group()->info($myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use index

```
$check = $adldap->group()->info($arr[0]);

$check = $adldap->group()->info($arr[1]);
```

and so on..

or you can use foreach

```
foreach($myArray as $value)
{
    $check = $adldap->group()->info($value);
}
```

you want to pass all array in a string use `implode()`