# How do i delete an element from an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, strpos

I have multiple arrays which are coming from a `foreach` loop. (See my last question for more info: [Array values in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381655/array-values-in-function))

Right here:

```
Array
(
    [count] => 1
    [0] => Array
        (
            [distinguishedname] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => CN=Beheergroep,OU=Test,DC=stefan,DC=nl
                )

            [0] => distinguishedname
            [count] => 1
            [dn] => CN=Beheergroep,OU=Test,DC=stefan,DC=nl
        )

)
Array
(
    [count] => 1
    [0] => Array
        (
            [distinguishedname] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => CN=Belangrijke Groep,OU=Test,DC=stefan,DC=nl
                )

            [0] => distinguishedname
            [count] => 1
            [dn] => CN=Belangrijke Groep,OU=Test,DC=stefan,DC=nl
        )

)
Array
(
    [count] => 1
    [0] => Array
        (
            [distinguishedname] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => CN=Domeingebruikers,CN=Users,DC=stefan,DC=nl
                )

            [0] => distinguishedname
            [count] => 1
            [dn] => CN=Domeingebruikers,CN=Users,DC=stefan,DC=nl
        )

)
Array
(
    [count] => 1
    [0] => Array
        (
            [distinguishedname] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => CN=Gebruikers,CN=Builtin,DC=stefan,DC=nl
                )

            [0] => distinguishedname
            [count] => 1
            [dn] => CN=Gebruikers,CN=Builtin,DC=stefan,DC=nl
        )

)
Array
(
    [count] => 1
    [0] => Array
        (
            [distinguishedname] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => CN=Hoofdgroep,OU=Test,DC=stefan,DC=nl
                )

            [0] => distinguishedname
            [count] => 1
            [dn] => CN=Hoofdgroep,OU=Test,DC=stefan,DC=nl
        )

)
Array
(
    [count] => 1
    [0] => Array
        (
            [distinguishedname] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => CN=Mailgroep,OU=Test,DC=stefan,DC=nl
                )

            [0] => distinguishedname
            [count] => 1
            [dn] => CN=Mailgroep,OU=Test,DC=stefan,DC=nl
        )

)
Array
(
    [count] => 1
    [0] => Array
        (
            [distinguishedname] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => CN=Securitygroep,OU=Securitygroups,DC=stefan,DC=nl
                )

            [0] => distinguishedname
            [count] => 1
            [dn] => CN=Securitygroep,OU=Securitygroups,DC=stefan,DC=nl
        )

)
Array
(
    [count] => 1
    [0] => Array
        (
            [distinguishedname] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => CN=Testgroep2,OU=Test,DC=stefan,DC=nl
                )

            [0] => distinguishedname
            [count] => 1
            [dn] => CN=Testgroep2,OU=Test,DC=stefan,DC=nl
        )

)
```

Now I want to check all the arrays for a specific value.

I'm using this function to check an array.

```
if(strpos($check[0]['distinguishedname'][0], 'OU=Test') !== false) {
```

If one of the arrays contain the specific value ("OU=Test") the need to be displayed otherwise the array needs to be excluded or hidden. How can I accomplish this?

**EDIT**

This is my code with the `foreach` loop.

```
$result = $adldap->user()->groups('stefan.guth');

for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
    sort($result);
}
print_r($result);

foreach ($result as $value) {
    $check = $adldap->group()->info($value, array(
        'distinguishedname'
    ));
    print_r($check);

    if (strpos($check[0]['distinguishedname'][0], 'OU=Test') === false) {

    }
}
```

Comment: That looks to be correct. How does it not work?

Comment: Yes the function is working. But how do I exclude or hide the arrays that NOT contain the specific value? With an `if` and `else`?

Comment: Currently you're doing `!== false`. Simply change it to `=== false`?

Comment: Ok thats simple but what do I put **after** the function which is an `if`?

Comment: Please post your current loop code in the question.

Comment: I edited my post. I don't know what to put after the last function to hide or exclude an array if the value is present.

Comment: So you just want to remove an element of your main array?

Comment: Yes remove/hide/exclude whatever. It's all about that it's not visible after the function with the check for a value.

Comment: So you Question is **How do i delete an element from an array in PHP?** right?

Comment: In the end, yes. If an array NOT contains a specific value then it needs to be deteled/hidden/excluded.

Comment: if you want to remove that then `unset()` it. (that key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want? You should change the foreach loop aswell..

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $check = $adldap->group()->info($value, array(
        'distinguishedname'
    ));
    print_r($check);

    if (strpos($check[0]['distinguishedname'][0], 'OU=Test') === false) {
        unset($result[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally! This works perfectly. I was stuck for days. Thank you very much!